# Can GDAL give the scale of a raster?

Tags: gdal, distance, legend, scale, gdal-translate

I have a GeoTIFF and I am trying to overlay a scale (miles or km) using GDAL.

Is there a function in GDAL that will do this?

I believe ArcPy has this functionality, but I am guessing GDAL does not - but wanted to check before I move on to my next question.

If there is no function for doing this - What would the best way be to get the scale?

My thoughts are, since I am using gdal.translate with projWin = [-2053514.581, 2702991.983, -2035515.049, 2691426.327], I can get the scale because these values are meter values.  Then I just need to create an overlay image based on that.

Comment: Will, I don't think GDAL has a utility to create a figure of a raster with a scale bar overlay. You may have better luck scripting this with Python (e.g. matplotlib, rasterio, etc.)

Comment: OK, thanks for the response Charlie.  Do I have the general thought right though - I am translating the image down using projWin, and then entering the meter values (upperleftX, upperleftY, lowerRightX, lowerRightY).  So, what I am thinking is I can subtract the two x's to get meters, then divide by 1609.34 to get miles.  Then I can overlay the scale with matplotlib.  
What are your thoughts on this?  Do I have it right or am I way off? :)

Comment: I think you have the right idea. The difference of the x coordinates will be the horizontal scale of the raster in meters, which you can then convert to miles.